# Associate a file to any row in any table of my database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

We are designing a system where our customer asks to be able to associate a file to any entity belonging to any table in the system.

Is this possible? How can our files table reference any entity in any table? We are thinking of GUIDs. But don't know if this is the correct way of implementing this feature or even if it's possible at all.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. using GUIDs seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

You create table with files listing.
Then you create reference to that record from any table you want.

Files table

```
id  FilePath
 1  C:\myfile
```

Some other table

```
id  fileReference   SomeOtherColumn
 1              1    some other data
```

Or if you really want to go this road then Files table will be

```
id  FilePath     OtherTableName   RecordIDinOtherTable
 1  C:\myfile    SomeOtherTable                      1
```

Comment: Files can point to ANY table in the system (not just one table)

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson Is it better now?

Comment: I don't feel this can be checked via constraints in the database. Don't know if GUIDs could be, either.

Comment: The version where you extend all tables to contain reference to files table can be checked by constraints. The version where you put table name in the column of course can't. You will not be able to even write query directly referencing that. And if by GUIDs you mean GUID of DB objects, then you are probably right and you will have hard time to write selects for it too. What is your approach of selecting data? Will you search for files related to specific record? Or will you search specific record by file name? And how about number of files to number of records? 1:1 or 1:N or N:M?

Comment: Marek, I'm still not convinced that these are the only solutions. Will wait a bit to see if someone else come's with a new idea before accepting your answer. Thanks

Comment: I have no problem with that. Maybe consider updating your question with as much detail as you can. Someone might come up with better solution then.

Comment: `OtherTableName` can be used only by constructing a `SELECT` and placing that value in it.  You can't use binding (etc).

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I am aware of that. It is the reason why I put it as last resort option. But maybe I should have been more explicit about it's dangers.

Comment: Problem I see (if I'm not wrong) with solution the first solution is that it assumes that each row will have only one file associated. What about having a central Files table and then each other table that can have files associated has its own Entity-Files table (e.g. documents-files, users-files, etc.) with a FK pointing to the Files table? However, Files won't be able to have FK, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The FK will go from Entity-FIles tables to Files table. So you will be going  Users => Users-Files => Files. In other words Files table will hold no information of what record in what table it is tied to.